# Piecewise function and differentiation quotient

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

**We have function $y = f(x) = |2x + 1|$**

**Can we simply say that $|2x + 1|' = 2$?**

No because if we use the chain rule then we get $\left(\left|2x+1\right|\right)'\:=\frac{2\left(2x+1\right)}{\left|2x+1\right|}$

**Redefine the same function piecewise without using the absolute value.**

$$\left|2x+1\right|=
\begin{cases} 
      2x+1 & x \geq -\frac12 \\
      -2x-1 & x \leq -\frac12 
   \end{cases}$$

**Calculate the differential quotient for each of the
corresponding regions.**

$f(x)=2x+1$

Differential quotient

$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x→x_0}
\frac{f(x) − f(x_0)}{x − x_0}.$$

$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x→x_0}
\frac{2x+1 − 2x_0-1}{x − x_0}=2$

$f(x)=-2x-1$

$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x→x_0}
\frac{-2x-1 + 2x_0+1}{x − x_0}=-2$

**What happens at $x = −\frac12$**?

> This is where I am confused. There is no x so that would mean that my
>   answer is wrong isn't it?

Comment: you don't have a function yet because at $x=-1/2$ it has two values

Comment: Once you fix that issue, remember that at the end of the day, the derivative is a limit of your difference quotient, or better put, the limit has to be the same whether taking left or right side limits...

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven But so far I my answers are alright? Then the only part that is missing is the function? I'm sorry I don't get your advice...

Comment: For your definition of the piecewise, you have  $$\left|2x+1\right|=
\begin{cases} 
      2x+1 & x \geq -\frac12 \\
      -2x-1 & x \leq -\frac12 
   \end{cases}$$  you can't have $x\le -1/2$ and $x\ge -1/2$.  But your approach is right thus far.  Now, are the two limits equal?  See my answer below...

Comment: Ok I kinda have a better understanding of what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for the limit of a difference quotient to exist, you must have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^{\color{red}{-}}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^{\color{red}{+}}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

You do not have that.  You have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^{\color{red}{-}}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=-2\neq 2=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^{\color{red}{+}}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

Therefore your functions is not differentiable at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

For $x_0> -1/2$ we have $f'(x_0)=2$ and For $x_0< -1/2$ we have $f'(x_0)=-2$.

Furthermore: $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0= -1/2$, since $\lim_{x→x_0+0}
\frac{f(x) − f(x_0)}{x − x_0} \ne \lim_{x→x_0-0}
\frac{f(x) − f(x_0)}{x − x_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x) = 2x+1$, then $f(-0.5)=0$.

Then we have $$\lim_{x \to x_0^+} \frac{2x+1-0}{x-(-0.5)}=2 \ne -2 = \lim_{x \to x_0^-}\frac{-2x-1-0}{x-(-0.5)}$$

Hence $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{2x+1-0}{x-(-0.5)}$ doesn't exist and it is not differetiable at that point.